# How do I get a CSS class to show up on screen multiple times

Tags: jquery, html, css

So if I have a sprite defined by the following CSS code:

```
#attack{
background-color: green;
width: 3px;
height: 10px;
position: absolute;
}
```

I can display it onscreen at whatever position I want using the following Jquery code:

```
$('#attack').css('left', X);
$('#attack').css('top', Y);
```

my question is how can i display it multiple times on the same screen? I think i have to change it to .attack but not sure exactly how that works if someone could help

Comment: Do you mean display them all at the same time or one by one?

Comment: A `#` selects an element by its ID and IDs must be unique. A `.` selects elements by a class, which can be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `#attack` you are assigning the styles to the element id. This implies there is only one of that element on the page. e.g.

```
<div id="attack"></div>
```

If  you want to use it in multiple places, you should use a class. so the syntax on your css would be `.attack` and in the element(s) it would look like this:

```
<div class="attack"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#attack` is not actually a css class; it's an ID. Classes are identified by a stop `.class`, while IDs are identified by a hashtag symbol `#id`.

IDs are unique and unrepeatable, while you can have unlimited elements with the same class.

If you want to apply the same style to different elements, you should use class.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on having multiple elements displayed, then you will want to set it to be an class instead of an id, as other answers have said.  Use `.attack` instead of `#attack`.

But, if you do `.attack`, then you cannot use your JQuery code to position these multiple instances, because `.attack` will select *all* of the elements with the `class="attack"`, and then will move them all to the same location.

What you want is to have both class AND id identifiers.  So, something like:

```
<div class="attack" id="attackOne"></div>
<div class="attack" id="attackTwo"></div>
```

Now, if you want to dynamically create these elements with JQuery, you can use the [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.  So, for instance, to create the second div from the first, you could do:

```
$(".attack").clone().attr('id', "attackTwo").appendTo(//wherever you want);
```

After that, you can use the id selector `#attackTwo` to position and use JQuery on just that one element.

https://jsfiddle.net/sxq06kce/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JS:

```
    $div =$(".attack");
    $div.clone(true).appendTo('body').css('left','480px');
    $div.clone(true).appendTo('body').css('left','700px');
```

`$div` just holds the selection of the `div` with the class ( not ID)  `attack`. You have to [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the `div`  and append it to `body` and then relocate it to whatever position you like.